# watij safari onclick method

Tags: html, testing, safari, macos, watij

I am trying to simulate the click event of an anchor tag using watij on mac. I found the tag

```
<a name="myLink" href="" onClick=""></a>
```

My code is

```
Tag link = spec.jquery("a[name=myLink]").click();
```

But it does not seem to work. Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Ankur Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

You might try altering your reference to the link. Ex., referencing it by `id` or `class`, as shown here:

```
<a href="" class="my_link">Hello</a>
```

-

```
Tag link = spec.jquery("a.my_link").click();
```

Additionally, although I am not familiar with Watij, at this point in the code, are you positive that the `<a>` element has finished loading? You need to verify that all elements in the DOM have loaded before you simulate actions against them.